# В чём разница между !str и strlen(str) и str!=NULL

Tags: c++

В чём разница между:

- `!str`
- `strlen(str)`
- `str!=NULL`

`str` - это `const char *str`
За что отвечает каждая из проверок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!str` эквивалентно `str==NULL`, это известный сишный подход. Я рекомендую всегда писать полностью, что бы избежать неоднозначностей. Как это работает? указатель в условиях интерпретируется как и число - nullptr(NULL)  - это ноль и это false, все остальное - true.

А вот это - `str!=NULL` противоположное. То есть, проверяем, что указатель не нулевой.

А вот `strlen(str)` - немного другое. Эта функция возвращает длину строки, поискав в ней нулевой символ. В условиях это проверка, что строка не пустая. То есть, если строка будет содержать `""`, то strlen вернет 0, а 0 - это false. В остальных случаях это будет истинна.

Важно помнить, что если strlen получает nullptr указатель, то будут проблемы. Функция внутри не обязана проверять указатель и сразу приступает к поиску нулевого символа. Обычно, отладочные версии библиотек это делают, но вот релизные - нет. Поэтому, часто проверка на непустую строку может выглядеть так

```
if (s != NULL && strlen(s) != 0) { ... }
```

P.S. я рекомендую всегда стараться писать полностью условие, хотя некоторые программисты очень любят экономить каждый символ.

Comment: анонимные минусаторы, прокомментируйте пожалуйста

Comment: По поводу рекомендаций:  Если речь идет о языке С, то согласен в некоторой степени.  В С++   могут быть объекты, которые не имеют оператора  ''==",  "!=",  но могут иметь  "operator bool " . Такими являются объекты из иерархии std::ios_base. Выражение if(std::cin!=0)  не будет компилирован.  Да, можно вместо if(cin)  написать if(cin.fail() !=0). Но  зачем такие сложности? И не все классы имеют подобную  возможность....Лично я, имею привычку сравнивать С++ объекты с типом bool, а там пусть компилятор сам выполнит автоматическое преобразование, если не имеется данного оператора.

Comment: я же не писал, что нужно сравнивать с нулем. я говорю о том, что условие нужно писать явно. Логично, что если что то имеет `operator bool()`, то конечно не стоит сравнивать с нулем. Ну и не писать что то вида `if (a == true) { return false; } else { return true;}` а просто `return !a;`;

Comment: согласен, особенно с возвращением булевского типа. Но в выражении if(Cplus_expr1 == true && Cexpr1==0 && Cexpr2!=0 && Cplusexpr2 != true) больше неоднозначности... Так что (ИМХО) вопрос такой же спорный, как и  вопрос о языке  кода в целом, как и вопрос о том написать  ::std::X  или  std::X.  Все таки  зависимо от того, что пишешь...

Comment: сложно рассуждать, смотря на сферические примеры. Иногда действительно нужно написать `i== false`, что бы подчеркнуть, что тут специально так написано. но к этому будет прилагаться ещё комментарий, который это объяснит. (например, потому что было `!i` и это вводило всех в ступор, все пытались переписать). А можно просто переименовать:)

Comment: И все же трудно удержаться от выражений типа `(s && strlen(s))` (особенно в макросах)

Comment: Если это си, то может и да. Но вот если это плюсы, то может лучше использовать std::string::empty?

Answer (score -1):

Первая проверка !str выдает true, если c-строка (массив из char) не  пустая, в противном случае false;

Вторая проверка strlen(str) считает количество элементов в массиве без учета нуль-терминатора;

Третья проверка str!=NULL выдает true, если указатель на массив сhar куда-то направлен, в противном случае false;

Comment: Вторая проверка strlen(str) считает количество элементов в массиве без учета нуль-терминатора;
А как понять условие if (strlen(str)) { //body}

Comment: будем честными, `strlen(str)` - это не проверка. Проверка должна возвращать хотя бы bool. А здесь просто длина строки.

Comment: ты же сам писал что если длинна 0 то это false

Comment: когда функция strlen оказывается в булевом контексте (if (strlen(str)) {}`, то да, 0 это false. Но если это `int a = strlen(str);`, то никакой не false/true